# Linq Dynamic Query tried to search data within a year get no results

Tags: linq

I am building a Dynamic query to search a collection of documents using LINQ. (please referred to Scott Gu's blog http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).

I can return the documents modified since last week, since last month without any problem! However, if I tried to return the documents last modified from last year to now. I got no result returned. And when I tried to get any documents modified a year ago, I got only one week results from 3 weeks ago)..

Does anyone know why? Below is my code:

```
 // tried to get last year till now: (no result)
 ( LastModifiedStr >= \"4/27/2014\" and LastModifiedStr <= \"4/28/2015\" )

 // tried to get documents older than one year. (results from 4/3/2015-4/9/2015)
 ( LastModifiedStr >= \"4/27/2014\"  )
```

Comment: Is LastModifiedStr a string or a DateTime?

Comment: If you compare strings, the comparison is beween strings, not dates. "14/1/2015" < "2/1/2015", because "1" < "2"

Comment: Thank you Stephen and xanatos..  You are right, I should've used the DateTime to compare!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare the string. The LastModified field should be a DateTime format, also inside your query builder, you probably want to convert the string to datetime as well. something like:

```
( LastModified >= Convert.ToDateTime(\"4/27/2014\") and LastModifiedStr <= Convert.ToDateTime(\"4/28/2015\") )
```